# Image Preprocessing for cave painting extraction

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

Please consider a sample image shown below

[image]

The cave paintings are vaguely seen here. Can you please suggest a probable image processing technique I can use here to extractthe regions of the painting?

I tried OTSU threshold, as it is a type of adaptive threshold, but it did not work. Something as simple as color segmentation can be looked into. Apart from that, any pointers please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use decorrelation stretching for this. Take a look at [this](http://www.dstretch.com/index.html). You'll find pre-processing techniques they are using in combination with decorrelation stretching to segment rock paintings. [Here](http://dhanushkadangampola.blogspot.com/2015/02/decorrelation-stretching.html) in my blog post you'll find an implementation of decorrelation stretching using OpenCV.